# Add widget to post-new.php i the dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can i add a custom widget to wp-admin/post-new.php?

Some themes use it, and i wan't to be able to do the same thing in my theme :)

Thanks

/Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for. Its called meta boxes and there are lots of tutorials how to implement them. Just Google it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create yourself a new side bar in functions.php, copy and paste one of the current ones, eg:

```
  register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => 'Primary Widget Area',
    'id' => 'primary_widget_area',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );
```

Change any references to `primary` to a name of your choice maybe `post-new`

Then add this side bar to wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php. Search for 'side-info-column'. Just before that div closes ad in the call to the new side bar:

```
<?php if ( is_sidebar_active('secondary_widget_area') ) : ?>
  <div id="secondary" class="widget-area">
    <ul class="xoxo">
      <?php dynamic_sidebar('secondary_widget_area'); ?>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Again, you can copy one of the current ones found in sidebar.php.

You can then go to dashboard > Appearance > Widgets and you should see your new sidebar there.

Hope that helps. I'll be happy to help more if needs be.

Comment: Hum... it works but is kind of nasty tho. Isn't messing with the wp core files useless if you want to keep your wp framework up to date since updating could replace the files you edited?There must be some other way. Wordpress has a great API for adding widgets to the start "dashboard". I just want to move them to the new page section o_O check out this article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API